# Matlab: Is there a way to evaluate a function handle with a variable length input vector?

Tags: function, matlab, vector, input, handle

Imagine you have the following easy code

```
vec=rand(p,1); % p can be anything
h = @(x_1,x_2,...,x_p) a*x_1+b*x_2+...k*x_p; % function handle with p scalar inputs
```

I want to evaluate h using the vector vec, i.e. h(vec(1),vec(2),...,vec(p)).
Unfortunately p can be anything such that this "brute force" method doesn't work. To put it in other words, i want to evaluate a function handle which gets p scalar inputs by using a vector of p elements but WITHOUT knowing p beforehand.  When working with symbolic expressions i found the nice "subs" routine:

```
a=subs(h_symb,vec_1,vec_2)
```

where the symbolic expression h_symb is evaluated by using the vector vec_2. Is there a similar way to cope with function handles?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`varargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614600/anonymous-function-with-a-variable-length-argument-list

Comment: If i get this correctly, varargin is used as the input parameter when defining the function handle. In my case, the function handle and its input variables are already given.  Can I easily switch from sth. like h= @(x1,x2,...) to h=@(varargin)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. If you're trying to use a vector of a known length *n* as the *n* inputs to a function, you can convert the vector to a comma-separated list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693072/using-vector-as-inputs-to-anonymous-function-in-matlab

Comment: An inefficient approach, but you could do cellvec = num2cell(vec); then h(cellvec{:});

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds like poor design. You might want to rethink your strategy. MATLAB is all about arrays, not scalars. You should be passing an array into your function.